# Sum Reduction (Binomial Theorem Related)

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem

I have the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\bigg\{\binom{n-1}{n-1-i}a^{(n-1-i)}\bigg[(1-a)^{i}\bigg(\frac{1-m^{n-i}}{n-i}\bigg)+\frac{m^{n-i}y^{i}}{n}\bigg]\bigg\}$$

It looks (obviously) quite similar to the binomial theorem in summation form. 
Any ideas on how to reduce this and express it as something other than a sum?

Comment: After distributing over the plus sign, the second part easily simplifies to $$\frac{m}{n}(am+y)^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a full answer, but I can't type it in a comment.  I'm not sure I'm good enough at MathJax to type it at all.  Let
$$\begin{align}
A_i&=\binom{n-1}{n-1-i}a^{n-1-i}\\
B_i&=(1-a)^i\left(\frac{1-m^{n-i}}{n-i}\right)\\
C_i&=\frac{m^{n-i}y^i}{n}
\end{align}$$
Then the given expression is $$
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{A_i(B_i+C_i)}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}A_iB_i+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}A_iC_i$$

It was the second term in the last expression that I was addressing in my comment.
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}A_iC_i=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\binom{n-1}{n-1-i}a^{n-1-i}}\frac{m^{n-i}y^i}{n}=\\
\frac{m}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\binom{n-1}{n-1-i}a^{n-1-i}m^{n-1-i}y^i}=\frac{m}{n}(am+y)^{n-1},
$$
by the binomial theorem.  So the original expression simplifies to $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}A_iB_i+\frac{m}{n}(am+y)^{n-1}$$

I was trying to say that in my comment without typing all this.

**EDIT** I believe I know how to do the second part also.  Let $$
f(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\binom{n-1}{k}\frac{x^{n-k}y^k}{n-k}},\text{ so that}\\
f_x(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\binom{n-1}{k}x^{n-1-k}y^k}=(x+y)^{n-1}\text{ and}\\
f(x,y)=\frac{(x+y)^n}{n}+C(y)\\
$$
Since f(0,y)=0, we have $C(y)=\frac{-y^n}{n}$ and $$
\boxed{f(x,y)=\frac{(x+y)^n-y^n}{n}}$$

Now you can write $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}A_iB_i$ as the sum of two terms, each of which is expressible in the form $f(x,y)$ times some constant.

Comment: ah ok thanks! that checks out. Any idea about the first term?

Comment: @WaitakereCity Not so far, I'm afraid.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much

Comment: @WaitakereCity My pleasure.